# IF Statement to insert into an Excel Power Query to un-Filter a Filter if Table Empty with Zero result

Tags: excel, powerquery

I have a Query in a sheet that refers to a cell for an Account Number to filter results from a Sequel Source returning transactions for that Sage Account Number. If the Account Number Cell is BLANK or the Account Number selected in the cell has no data, I am wanting the Filter step to un-Filter altogether and return the Table with all sourced transactions for all Account Numbers.

Is there some way of inserting an IF Condition Statement into my Query, that IF the Table is Blank returnng Zero results, that the Filter Step Un-Filters altogether?

VBA won't work as once the Table returns Blank/Zero, nothing to un_Filter so would have to be a Condition Statement in the Query.

My code after inserting your suggestion is as follows:-

```
let
MonthNo= Text.From(Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="MonthNo"]}[Content]{0}[Column1]), 
Source = Sql.Database("XXXX\SAGE200", "UKXXXXXXXLtd", [Query="SELECT #(lf)NLNominalAccount.AccountNumber, NLNominalAccount.AccountCostCentre, NLNominalAccount.AccountDepartment, NLNominalAccount.AccountName,#(lf)NLPostedNominalTran.TransactionDate, NLPostedNominalTran.PostedDate, NLPostedNominalTran.GoodsValueInBaseCurrency, NLPostedNominalTran.Reference,#(lf)NLPostedNominalTran.Narrative, NLPostedNominalTran.UniqueReferenceNumber, NLPostedNominalTran.UserName, NLPostedNominalTran.UserNumber,#(lf)SYSAccountingPeriod.PeriodNumber#(lf)FROM NLPostedNominalTran, NLNominalAccount, SYSAccountingPeriod, SYSFinancialYear#(lf)WHERE NLPostedNominalTran.NLNominalAccountID = NLNominalAccount.NLNominalAccountID#(lf)AND NLPostedNominalTran.SYSAccountingPeriodID = SYSAccountingPeriod.SYSAccountingPeriodID#(lf)AND SYSAccountingPeriod.SYSFinancialYearID = SYSFinancialYear.SYSFinancialYearID#(lf)AND SYSAccountingPeriod.PeriodNumber <="&MonthNo&"#(lf)ORDER BY NLPostedNominalTran.UniqueReferenceNumber DESC"]),
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"TransactionDate", type date}, {"GoodsValueInBaseCurrency", Currency.Type}, {"PostedDate", type date}}),
Custom1 = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Date Time Refresh", each DateTime.LocalNow() as datetime),
#"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Custom1,{{"Date Time Refresh", type datetime}}),
#"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Changed Type1",{{"AccountNumber", "Account Number"}, {"AccountCostCentre", "Cost Centre"}, {"AccountDepartment", "Department"}, {"AccountName", "Account Name"}, {"TransactionDate", "Trans Date"}, {"PostedDate", "Posted Date"}, {"GoodsValueInBaseCurrency", "Posted Value"}, {"Reference", "Journal Ref"}, {"Narrative", "Journal Narrative"}, {"UniqueReferenceNumber", "URN"}, {"UserName", "User Name"}, {"UserNumber", "User Number"}, {"PeriodNumber", "Posted Period"}}),
#"Changed Type2" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Renamed Columns",{{"Posted Value", Currency.Type}}),
#"Duplicated Column" = Table.DuplicateColumn(#"Changed Type2", "Trans Date", "Trans Date - Copy"),
#"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Duplicated Column",{"Account Number", "Cost Centre", "Department", "Account Name", "Trans Date", "Posted Date", "Posted Value", "Journal Ref", "Journal Narrative", "URN", "User Name", "User Number", "Trans Date - Copy", "Posted Period", "Date Time Refresh"}),
#"Extracted Year" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Reordered Columns",{{"Trans Date - Copy", Date.Year, Int64.Type}}),
#"Renamed Columns1" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Extracted Year",{{"Trans Date - Copy", "Year"}}),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Renamed Columns1", "Full Account No", each [Account Number]&[Cost Centre]&[Department]),
#"Reordered Columns1" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Added Custom",{"Full Account No", "Account Number", "Cost Centre", "Department", "Account Name", "Trans Date", "Posted Date", "Posted Value", "Journal Ref", "Journal Narrative", "URN", "User Name", "User Number", "Year", "Posted Period", "Date Time Refresh"}),
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Reordered Columns1", each Text.From([Full Account No]) = Text.From(Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="AccountNo"]}[Content]{0}[Column1])),
checkstep = if Table.RowCount(#"Filtered Rows")=0 then #"Reordered Columns1" else #"Filtered Rows",
#"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Filtered Rows",{{"Year", Order.Ascending}, {"Posted Period", Order.Ascending}, {"Trans Date", Order.Ascending}})
```

in
#"Sorted Rows"

And when D3 is Blank or F3 returns zero and the Table returns Blank/Zero lines in the Table, then I am needing Output Table to revert to the `#"Reordered Columns1"` step and then the final `#"Sorted Rows"` step.

[image]

Thanks for your help

Gary

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do a check after your filter step

```
checkstep = if Table.RowCount(#"filtered-step-name-here")=0 then #"step-name-before-filter-here" else #"filtered-step-name-here",
```

simple example -- data goes away in step 2 and comes back in step 3

```
let Source =#table({"Column1","Column2"}, {{"a","d"}, {"b","d"}, {"c","d"},{"d","d"}}),
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(Source, each ([Column2] <> "d")),
#"Test" = if Table.RowCount(#"Filtered Rows") = 0 then Source else #"Filtered Rows"
in #"Test"
```

Comment: Hi horseyride, appreciated for the help. I have inserted as you suggested above checkstep, and am still getting a Blank/Zero lines Table.
...
    #"Reordered Columns1" = .....,
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Reordered Columns1", each Text.From([Full Account No]) = Text.From(Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="AccountNo"]}[Content]{0}[Column1])),
    checkstep = if Table.RowCount(#"Filtered Rows")=0 then #"Reordered Columns1" else #"Filtered Rows",
    #"Sorted Rows" = ........
Have tried #"Check" = but won't give what I need, if Table returns Blank/Zero rows on the Filtered step.

Comment: Thanks horseyride, will play around with. I have edited question above with my code to give more context. Will see what can do. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Hi horseyride, thank you, I have got it to work, using your Simple Example and then moved the Check step to the very last step instead of before the last Sorted Rows step.
Thank you very much.